# Is there a trigonometric expression for this sequence with higher radicals (possibly related to Fermat Primes)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Consider sequence $\frac13,\frac1{5^{1/2}},\dots,\frac1{(2^{2^k}+1)^{1/2^k}},\dots$.
$$\frac13=\frac{ \cos(\pi/3)}{\cos(\pi/3)+1}$$
$$\frac1{5^{1/2}}=\frac{\cos(\pi/5)}{\cos(\pi/5)+1}$$
holds but later values do not hold.

Is there a single expression that can explain the whole series trigonometrically at least for Fermat primes?

In other words is there a bivariate polynomial $f(x,y)\in\Bbb Q[x,y]$ that vanishes at $\Big({(2^{2^k}+1)^{1/2^k}},\cos\Big(\frac\pi{2^{2^k}+1}\Big)\Big)$ at every $k\in\Bbb Z$ at least when $2^{2^k}+1$ is a Fermat prime?

Comment: My first thought is to look at the proof (Gauss) of the case k=2 that the regular 17-gon is Euclidean-constructible and see what it says about the value of $\cos (\pi /17)$.

Comment: Now posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/256649/can-the-capacity-of-17-and-65537-cycle-be-achievable-at-finite-powers with no mention of the previous post here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson this is clearly a diffeent problem and you know it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, for $p>2$, we have,
$$\frac{\cos\frac{\pi}{p}}{cos\frac{\pi}{p}+1}=\left(1-\frac{1}{\cos\frac{p-1}{p}\pi}\right)^{-1}$$
with $p$ ***not*** necessarily a prime. For prime $p$, the $\text{RHS}$ is an algebraic number of degree $k=\frac{p-1}2$.

Thus, for $p=3,5$ the degrees are $k=1,2$ as you observed, but for $p=17$, the $\text{RHS}$ is a root of an octic, breaking the pattern of its precursors' simple forms.